# In window worker service dot net core while connectiong to database i am getting error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: WindowServiceSample1.Worker': Cannot consume scoped service 'WindowServiceSample1.Data.ApplicationDbContext' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'.)

```
 using WindowServiceSample1;
using WindowServiceSample1.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
 
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseWindowsService(options =>
    {
        options.ServiceName = "Abc Service New";
    })
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {   
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("Server=DESKTOP-4NUBQP8\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;"));

    })
    .Build();
    await host.RunAsync();
```

Worker class code -

```
namespace WindowServiceSample1
{
    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _db = db;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {

                Notification item = new Notification();
                item.EUID = "test";
                item.StoreNumber = "test";
                item.NotificationType = "test";
                item.Status = "test";

                _db.Notifications.Add(item);
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                
                _logger.LogWarning("ABC Service running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Application DB Context class

```
namespace WindowServiceSample1.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
 
        public DbSet<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error shows we should consume scope services in scoped instances to avoid data corruption or threading issue.

You should use Using ServiceScopeFactory to resolve scope instances.

Like this:

```
    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, , IServiceScopeFactory factory )
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _db = factory.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
   }

    }
```